# Создать логический диск из нескольких дисков и ПК

Tags: linux, сервер, файловая-система

Суть в том, чтобы подключить несколько разношёрстных дисков, разной степени убитости на нескольких компах и объединить их в один логический. При этом необходимо как то дублировать информацию на случай выхода из строя одного из дисков. Это необходимо для файловой свалки, и бекапов дисков целиком. ОС Ubuntu 16.04.
Имеется ли какое нибудь готовое решение, которое можно развернуть?

Comment: есть такая штука - [ceph](https://habrahabr.ru/company/performix/blog/218065/).

Comment: Т.е. диски будут НЕ внутри одного физического компа, я всё правильно понял? И на каждом из компов будет запущена операциока?

Comment: @donRumata Вы всё верно поняли

Comment: Можно взять [Gluster](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlusterFS), в отличие от ceph ему не нужен выделенный сервер метаданных (да и по нашим измерениям, он оказался побыстрее (возможно из-за поддержки RDMA, чего скорее всего у вас нет))

Comment: @avp, а разве нода ceph не может одновременно выполнять несколько ролей?

Comment: @donRumata, по идее может, но  были у нас какие-то проблемы (сейчас уже не помню точно) с разделением дисков под данные и метаданные на том же узле.

Comment: @avp составьте ответ https://habrahabr.ru/post/251931/ я зачту. желательно с тем вариантом которого нет в статье а именно использование 4-х серверов, 2 для реплики. Данные записывать через Distributed Striped

Comment: @shaman888, спасибо за доверие, но должен отказаться, поскольку эту работу делал не я, а коллега. Просто увидел вопрос на как-то знакомую тему и решил подкинуть ссылку. Думаю, вы сами разберетесь и напишете замечательный самоответ.